# Why is Rudin's real and complex analysis considered esoteric?

Tags: soft-question

I glanced over the fist few chapters. This book seems quite standard. Proofs are written in a "user-friendly" manner expanding on details that should be obvious to graduate students. Why do most Professors avoid using this book as if it's some sort of monstrosity?

Comment: I've never heard it called "esoteric".

Comment: It is considered "elegant" (perhaps to the point of terseness) but a very standard first-year graduate math textbook.

Comment: Maybe its above their heads.

Comment: I don't feel that Rudin proofs are written to be "elegant". I checked a few theorems and it appears to be using some of the more intuitive rather than "elegant" arguments, which I think is a good thing.

Comment: It's a great, well written book which is why it's so popular and used in courses frequently. The book covers a large amount of difficult material, so the book is considered to be challenging.